# Coloured output subject to user defined pattern

Tags: bash

I am interested in writing a bash function that prints the contents of a variable and highlights all the lines that match a given pattern.

The following uses `awk` to process the lines in the variable.  But this does not work on a pattern for matching but by specifying the lines to be coloured (e.g. lseq="2,3,5").

```
aid ()
 {  
  local -r sgr="$( tput sgr0 )"  
  local -r blu="$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )"
  
  awk -v frg="$blu" -v rst="$sgr" -v lnum="$lseq" ptrn="$rl" \
    'BEGIN { split(lnum, laggr, ",") }
      {
       found = 0
       for (item in laggr) {
         if (laggr[item] == NR) { found = 1 ; break }
        }
       if (found) { print frg $0 rst }
       else { print $0 }
      }' <<< "$@"
 }
```

For instance, I have the following multiline variable, where I want to print lines beginning with `edvart` to use a blue foreground.

```
rl="^[[:space:]]*edvart .*$"
var="
Here is an example
  edvart -W
Some description
Introduction
Menu
Interactive"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? The code you've included is just boiler plate code for recognizing the input.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You want to print all the lines from a given variable; and within the printout, you want to highlight lines that match a given pattern?

Comment: Correct.  That in the intention,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the main ingredients to solve the problem:

1. Use `tput` to colorize
2. Put the source text into the pipeline
3. Process the lines

Here is a solution using `while`/`read`

```
rst=$( tput sgr0 ) ; hi=$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )

printf '%s\n' "$source" \
| while read line
do
  if [[ "$line" =~ "$pattern" ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "${hi}${line}${rst}"
  else
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  fi
done
```

Note that the `=~` syntax is specific to bash. It's possible to use `grep` instead and leverage its exit status in the if-statement, but I won't show that here since you tagged the question with "bash".

Here's a solution with `awk`:

```
rst=$( tput sgr0 ) ; hi=$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )
printf '%s\n' "$source" \
| awk '{
  if ( $0 ~ /'"$pattern"'/ ) {
    printf "'${hi}'%s'${rst}'\n", $0
  } else {
    print
  }
}'
```

And another solution with `sed`:

```
rst=$( tput sgr0 ) ; hi=$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )
printf '%s\n' "$source" | sed "/$pattern/s/^.*$/${hi}&${rst}/"
```

In the case of `awk` and `sed`, I'm technically embedding the color/formatting in the awk/sed script. So really the `hi` and `rst` variables aren't needed. But I figured it made it easier to read.

The `awk` and `sed` solutions are more portable than the `read` solution, working on any POSIX compliant system.

If you want to highlight just the matched string instead of the entire line, I would just recommend `sed`.

```
rst=$( tput sgr0 ) ; hi=$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )
printf "$source" | sed "s/$pattern/${hi}&${rst}/g"
```

Comment: I like the `awk` version. There is also the possibility to call `match`.  What do you think about that?

Comment: Given your original requirements, `match`  seems unnecessary. I'm going to guess that `match` would be slower because of the extra things that it does. But if you have some fancier handling in mind that requires `match`, go nuts!

Comment: If you're envisioning highlighting the matched string and not just the entire line, then I would recommend `sed` instead.

Comment: Would there be any backlash about using `<<< "$@"` ?

Comment: That syntax is less portable since it's specific to bash. But if you're already planning for a bash-specific script, then that's fine.